# Colocar imagem local no body ao enviar um email

Tags: c#, envio-de-email

Para enviar um email a partir da aplicação estou a usar o `MailMessage` disponibilizado. Agora estou a tentar colocar uma imagem no body do email via html:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpCliente = new SmtpClient(server);
...
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Body += "<br />Cumprimentos,<br />";
mail.Body += "<img src=\"D://MediaOleotorres/logoOleotorresAssinatura.png\" height=\"42\" width=\"42\">";
```

No entanto ao enviar o email, a imagem não aparece. Será que tenho de usar uma imagem que esteja disponibilizada online?

**EDIT:**
Também já tentei colocar a imagem como anexada e depois adiciona-la ao body, é possível?

```
string attachmentPath = @"D:/MediaOleotorres/imagens/logoOleotorresAssinatura.png";
Attachment inline = new Attachment(attachmentPath);
inline.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
inline.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
inline.ContentType.MediaType = "image/png";
inline.ContentType.Name = Path.GetFileName(attachmentPath);

mail.Attachments.Add(inline);
```

Comment: Você pode aceitar sua própria resposta neste caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já encontrei uma solução, que passa por criar um novo atalho da imagem local que se pretende adicionar ao corpo da mensagem e adicionar o mesmo ao corpo:

```
            var contentID = "Image";
            var inlineLogo = new Attachment(@"D://MediaOleotorres/logoOleotorresAssinatura.png/logoOleotorresAssinatura.png");
            inlineLogo.ContentId = contentID;
            inlineLogo.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
            inlineLogo.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
            mail.Attachments.Add(inlineLogo);
            mail.Body += "<br /><br /><img src=\"cid:" + contentID + "\" height=\"42\" width=\"42\"><br />";
```

Comment: ainda acho que o mais correto seria essa imagem estar hospedada online

Comment: Sim, também penso que sim. Mas é daqueles casos que o cliente é que "sabe"

Comment: com certeza te entendo

Comment: Eu sei, só não vim ao SO no fim de semana para o fazer :P